# Add buttons to a jpg image

Tags: android

I would like to use the following image and have 2 invisible buttons where is "`Select Colour`" and "`Select Type`". I know I should use the image as background but my problem is how to add the buttons on the image on those specific locations for every time the user clicks on them, they do open different fragments.

[image]

Comment: Use position in css

Comment: Why don't you use two TextViews, instead? The can be made clickable. It's easier to have a green parent and two transparent children (TextViews are transparent by default)

Comment: @Sodhisaab Its an Android Question

Comment: @ModularSynth because this is a part of the image...

Comment: I only see a green square. It makes no sense to me to have it as an image.

Comment: If you are using the same background you can also use ImageButtons and set a custom image to them

Comment: Without having to color match, TextViews are a valid alternative.

Comment: @ModularSynth I think the OP requests that make custom parts of image clickable, though yes he can simply place two TextViews

Comment: @NovoLucas ... and greatly simplify their life: A color (or an image) and 2 TextViews - DONE!

Comment: Think on layers. You can use as an example a frame layout where the lower layer is the image and over it there is another layer with text only buttons.

Comment: @ModularSynth please publish your answer for I can accept it.

Comment: Oh, well. Too late. Someone else already did. ;)

Comment: @ModularSynth I will accept yours because you were the first one. Please publish your answer.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated. But I would feel like "stealing" an existing answer to someone else. And it would feel just wrong, to me.

Comment: @ModularSynth you were who gave the solution.....

Comment: More of a suggestion, than a real answer. You understood the concept from a few words and were able to take advantage from it. Therefore, it's been a teamwork, after all. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_off"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/above"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="Select color"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="Select type"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

With a result like this:

[image]